# R - remove column when the values are all the same

Tags: r

In R I have a table with columns:

```
 $ minEDGE     : num  55 13 37 22 40 34 65 37 62 45 
 $ diagonalEDGE: num  401 506 520 591 529 526 607 715 607 713 
 $ maxECC      : num  100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100 100
```

I want to delete the column which consists of one specific value only (e.g. `100` in column `maxECC`)

Result should be:

```
$ minEDGE     : num  55 13 37 22 40 34 65 37 62 45 
$ diagonalEDGE: num  401 506 520 591 529 526 607 715 607 713
```

It would also be interesting for non-integer values (e.g. chars or strings), which can't be solved by calculating the variance.

Comment: Sorry for the dublicate, I just asked the wrong question while searching

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Filter`

```
Filter(var, df1)
```

Or

```
Filter(function(x) length(unique(x))==1, df1)
```

Comment: FYI: In addition I found: df <- df[,-nearZeroVar(df)] of the caret-package